# Storing grid-like data and performing lookups

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two-dimensional grid (example visualized below) and am hoping to better understand...

1. The most "pythonic" way to store such data
2. How to perform a lookup given coordinates *with decimals* - that is, the "tier" where tier <= value < next tier

Lookup examples:

- x=1.35 and y=58.00 would return "F"
- x=2.00 and y=24.99 would return "C"
- x=2.00 and y=25.00 would return "G"

[image]

Initial sloppy thought was this:

```
lookupData = {
    0 : { 0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D" },
    25 : { 0: "E", 1: "F", 2: "G", 3: "H"},
    ...
}
```

Some Googling has also pointed to numpy arrays as a good potential solution. Any/all advice is greatly appreciated - please let me know if can provide more detail. Just looking to start off using an efficient method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach - make it a nested `list` and use some simple arithmetic/type-cast for the lookup:

```
values = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]

lookup = lambda grid, x, y: grid[int(y) // 25][int(x)]

lookup(values, 2.3, 24.99)
# 'C'
lookup(values, 2.5, 25.00)
# 'G'
```

If your y-axis marks are given as an irregular sorted list, you can use `bisect` to find the correct index in logarithmic time:

```
from bisect import bisect

y_axis = [0, 25, 75, 190, 225]

lookup = lambda grid, x, y: grid[bisect(y_axis, y) - 1][int(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However, my example was accidentally a bit misleading. The increments are not necessarily consistent. I.e. the Y-axis could theoretically be 0, 25, 75, 190, 225, etc. Do you mind taking another look with that in mind? Much appreciated. Editing question to reflect.

Comment: That makes it more complicated :) I amended my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `pandas` - it is very suitable for your task:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D"},
    25: {0: "E", 1: "F", 2: "G", 3: "H"},
    60: {0: "I", 1: "J", 2: "K", 3: "L"},
    90: {0: "M", 1: "N", 2: "O", 3: "P"}})

df = df.T
print(df)
print()

for x, y in [(1.35, 58), (2, 24.99), (2, 25)]:
    idx = df.index.searchsorted(y, side='right')
    col = df.columns.searchsorted(x, side='right')
    print(df.iloc[idx - 1, col - 1])
```

Output:

```
    0  1  2  3
0   A  B  C  D
25  E  F  G  H
60  I  J  K  L
90  M  N  O  P

F
C
G
```